# Phonegap Native Notifications - unwanted "optional" parameters stay visible

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I have developed a helper function for creating native notifications in phonegap and it works fine except for one thing... when I leave out the optional parameters the `navigator.notification.prompt` adds in it's own default values like `"default text"` or `"prompt message"`.

Now, quick fix is to insert a non-empty string `" "` as `undefined`, `null` and empty strings `""` don't work.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or intentional? Or have I missed something in my helper function? As I said, the prompts are working and giving results and all, it's just the optional parameters give in crappy defaults when not used.

Code is as follows:

```
var Helper = {  // Hilfs Klasse, mit diversen Funktionen
    alert:function(message, callback, title, buttonName){   //Ruft im Browser ein standard "Alert" auf und in der App ein Natives "Alert"
        if (!callback) callback = function () { };
        if (navigator.notification !== undefined && navigator.notification.alert !== undefined) {  // Prüfungs ob die native Funktion verfügbar ist.
            navigator.notification.alert(
                message,
                callback,
                title ? title : "Info",
                buttonName);
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.alert(message);
                callback();
            },0);
        }
    },
    //Ruft im Browser ein standard "confirm" auf und in der App ein Natives "confirm"
    confirm:function(message, callback, title, buttonLabels){
        if(navigator.notification !== undefined && navigator.notification.confirm !== undefined){ // Prüfungs ob die native Funktion verfügbar ist.
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                message,
                callback,
                title ? title : "Bestätigen",
                buttonLabels ? buttonLabels : ["OK", "Abbrechen"]
            );
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                callback(window.confirm(message) ? 1 : 2);
            },0);
        }
    },

    //Ruft im Browser ein standard "prompt" auf und in der App ein Natives "prompt"
    prompt:function(message, callback, title, defaultValue, buttonLabels){
        if(navigator.notification !== undefined && navigator.notification.prompt !== undefined){ // Prüfungs ob die native Funktion verfügbar ist.
            navigator.notification.prompt(
                message,
                callback,
                title,
                buttonLabels ? buttonLabels : ["OK", "Abbrechen"],
                defaultValue ? defaultValue : undefined);
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                var result =  window.prompt(message, defaultValue);
                callback({
                    buttonIndex: result !== null ? 1 : 2,
                    input1:result
                });
                callback();
            },0);
        }
    }


};

function scanFunction() {
    var deviceToAdd = null;
    if (isMobileDevice()) {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                deviceToAdd = result.text;
                if (deviceToAdd != "") {
                    Helper.confirm(
                        ("Gerät " + deviceToAdd + " hinzufügen?"),
                        onConfirmScan,
                        "Gerät hinzufügen"
                    );
                }
                else {
                    Helper.prompt(
                        " ",
                        onConfirmPrompt,
                        "Gerät manuell hinzufügen",
                        " "
                    )
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                Helper.alert("Fehler: " + error);
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        deviceToAdd = prompt("Gerät hinzufügen");
        if (deviceToAdd != null) {
            Server.registerDevice(deviceToAdd, loadDevices);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notification plugin of 
[PhoneGap notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

When you look at the js code for prompt, you have :

```
prompt: function(message, resultCallback, title, buttonLabels, defaultText) {
    var _message = (message || "Prompt message");
    var _title = (title || "Prompt");
    var _buttonLabels = (buttonLabels || ["OK","Cancel"]);
    var _defaultText = (defaultText || "");
    exec(resultCallback, null, "Notification", "prompt", [_message, _title, _buttonLabels, _defaultText]);
},
```

This part may interest you : `var _title = (title || "Prompt");` because you can't use an empty string as title.